# Laravel update array syntax

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble doing a record update array via POST in Laravel.

I have captured all the post data in an array cant update array achievement

```
<form action="{{'updateapp'}}" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" class="id" name="id[]" value="{{ $quarter->id }}" />
<input type="text" name="achv[]" value="{{ $quarter->achievement }}">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Controller :

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->id;
    $achvs = $request->achv;
    DB::table('quarters')->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->update(array(['achievement' => $achvs ]));   

    return redirect('evaluator');      
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have set [] array in your form, you can access it as following

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->id[0];
    $achvs = $request->achv[0];
    DB::table('quarters')->where('id', $ids)
    ->update(['achievement' => $achvs ]);   

    return redirect('evaluator');      
  }
```

if you want to update multiple rows then use following code:

```
foreach($request->id as $key => $value){ 

      $quarters = Quarters::find($request->id[$key]); 
      $quarters->achievement = $request->achv[$key]; 
      $quarters->save(); 
}
```

Comment: FatalThrowableError in Grammar.php line 118:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\sofia-project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 376

Comment: your question little confusing now. please explain in detail what do you want exactly.

Comment: I understood properly, I have update my answer. please check above code

Answer (score 0):

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->id[0];
    $achvs = $request->achv[0];
    DB::table('quarters')->where('id', $ids)
    ->update(array(['achievement' => $achvs,'achievement1' => $achvs1]));
    return redirect('evaluator');      
  }
```

Comment: While all answers are appreciated, it is very good to have some detail and explanation in your answer, so that people with similar problems can understand it too.